# Eloquent-oauth - catching PDO Exception

Tags: php, oauth, error-handling, laravel-5

Although this question is about a specific package it should be relevant to other packages as it is really about where in the Laravel framework to correctly trap for the situation below.

I am using [eloquent-oauth](https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth) to enable login via linkedin and facebook to my app.

Authorizing and logging in both work fine individually.

However if I have previously authorized and logged in via one social platform and then try to authorize with another I get a PDO exception that the insert fails on the unique email constraint on my user table.

Where should I trap for that insertion?

I can see that I can add in code to the vendor folder directly but don't think that is good practise as that would surely be overwritten if I upgraded the package at some point in the future?

What I am currently doing is to add a user check into the vendor/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth/src/OAuthManager.php file in the login function

```
public function login($providerAlias, Closure $callback = null)
{
    if (! $this->stateManager->verifyState()) 
    {
        throw new InvalidAuthorizationCodeException;
    }
    $details = $this->getProvider($providerAlias)->getUserDetails();

    //start of existing user check
    $thisUser = User::where('email', $details->email)->first();
    if ($thisUser !== null)
        {
            $autoOpenModalLogin = true; //instruct the page to open the login modal
            return redirect()->guest('home')->with('$autoOpenModalLogin', $autoOpenModalLogin);
        }
    //end of existing user check
    return $this->authenticator->login($providerAlias, $details, $callback);
}
```

I thought it might be an better to add it into the route somewhere - but I can't seem to trap that error. Is there something else I should add below to catch a PDO error?

```
Route::get('{provider}/login', function ($provider) {
try {
    OAuth::login($provider, function ($user, $userDetails) {
    $user->email = $userDetails->email;
    $user->name = $userDetails->firstName . ' ' . $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->first_name = $userDetails->firstName;
    $user->last_name = $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->save();
    });
    return view('home');
} catch (ApplicationRejectedException $e) {
    // User rejected application
} catch (InvalidAuthorizationCodeException $e) {
    // Authorization was attempted with invalid
    // code,likely forgery attempt
}
});
```

I guess if I keep it the inserted user check in the vendor files I will just need to update those if I ever update the package?

But is there a better way to do it than what I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I added in a catch for a PDOexception and that seems to be exactly what I need! Will check it first and then confirm here.

```
Route::get('{provider}/login', function ($provider) {
try {
    OAuth::login($provider, function ($user, $userDetails) {
    $user->email = $userDetails->email;
    $user->name = $userDetails->firstName . ' ' . $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->first_name = $userDetails->firstName;
    $user->last_name = $userDetails->lastName;
    $user->save();
    });
    return view('home');
} catch (ApplicationRejectedException $e) {
// User rejected application
} catch (InvalidAuthorizationCodeException $e) {
// Authorization was attempted with invalid
// code,likely forgery attempt
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    $autoOpenModalLogin = true;
    return redirect()->guest('home')->with('$autoOpenModalLogin', $autoOpenModalLogin);
}   
});
```

Comment: Ok, was such a simple solution - I guess I was caught up in trying to access the user info!